# Where should user data be stored for a VS Extensions?

Tags: visual-studio, vsix

I'm creating a VS 2012 Plugin via a VSIX project.  The user will have the ability to save some custom settings.  Is there a preferred location to store this data so that during an update the data is not overwritten?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your settings page is derived from [DialogPage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.dialogpage.aspx), you can use the [SaveSettingsToStorage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.dialogpage.savesettingstostorage) method. I would recommend this path for options appropriate for display in Tools > Options (which is basically anything that's not specific to a particular project or solution, since that's where the user expects to find options).

If your options are specific to a solution or project there are other interfaces which you can use (I believe the [IVsSolutionPersistence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.interop.ivssolutionpersistence.aspx) service interface is one), but I'm not quite as familiar with these.

Comment: I need to store a whole bunch of data in xml and the DialogPage tells me it is too big to be stored there. What would be the prefered folder?

Answer (score 1):

There is no such preferred location to store user data in Visual Studio Extensibility.

I guess the place to store user data for your plugin is out of VSX guidelines, and totally up to you. You could Ither use user folder, or registry, or whatever else.